# Ошибка при запуске: Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК

Tags: c#, .net

Приложение написано в Visual Studio 2017

Target framework: .NET Framework 3.5

Output type: Windows Application

Platform target: Any CPU ( пробовал ставить x64, на проблему не влияет )

Приложение запускается на терминальных серверах c Windows 2012r2 и 2008r2 (x64)
Приложение вставлено в автозагрузку. Может нормально запускаться месяц,два, полгода, а потом у всех пользователей на каком-нибудь сервере вдруг начинает выдавать ошибку: *"Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК. Чтобы найти версию для вашего компьютера, обратитесь к издателю приложения."*

Для исправления ошибки достаточно переименовать исполняемый файл и программа отлично запускается. Проходит, какое-то время и снова ошибка. Происходит это, как на 2012, так и на 2008 серверах.
Есть предположения о причине такого поведения ?

Comment: `потом у всех пользователей на каком-нибудь сервере` только на одном сервере, а на других работает? Или на всех серверах разом? Какой `.NET Framework` установлен на сервере? Что то есть в EventLog?

Comment: Перестает запускаться только на одном сервере. На персональных ПК ошибка ни разу не возникала. Программа запускается с сетевого ресурса. В журналах ошибка ни как себя не проявляет. .net 3.5 установлена точно. 4 версии тоже какие-то ставятся автоматом. Обновления на сервера регулярно устанавливаются.

Comment: SmartScreen или что-то подобное стоит?

Comment: процесса SmartScreen не нашел. Есть Каспер, ну он обычно как-то семафорит о срабатывании. Остальное типовой офисный софт.

Comment: "Программа запускается с сетевого ресурса" - я правильно понимаю, что на сетевой шаре лежит exe, который пользователь запускает двойным кликом прямо с шары на своем компе? Тогда надо искать грабли на машинах пользователей, потому что в таком режиме приложение работает именно на машине пользователя, а на шаре лежит только исходный образ исполняемого модуля, сервер тут вообще ни при чем.